# Combine docpad run and grunt watch

Tags: gruntjs, watch, docpad

I'm using docpad and for local development I start him with `docpad run` and it runs and become an active process in terminal.

And I'm using grunt and I have `watch` command that compiles my stylus files. And I'm running `grunt watch` in another terminal tab and it's starts another active process.

Can I combine these tools in one command and one active process? I tried [grunt-shell](http://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-shell) and started `grunt watch` and `docpad run` in one tool, but docpad in that case doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a Grunt plugin for DocPad: https://github.com/robloach/docpad-plugin-grunt

As I understand it, it just basically runs Grunt on the project every time DocPad re-generates. So it's not exactly what you're asking for but it works. :)

Comment: Thank you, but I think this wont help, because changing stylus files wont trigger DocPad regenerating.

Comment: Yes it will. Do you have the Stylus plugin installed? https://github.com/docpad/docpad-plugin-stylus

Comment: No, I have only grunt plugins for such tasks. Will try it today! But I prefer to separate these tools: docpad for site structure, grunt for css/js. Now I see that this philosophy was wrong. But I can run two watch tools same time as later)

Comment: Grunt is usually used for minifying tasks if used along DocPad. https://github.com/Greduan/eduantech.docpad/blob/master/Gruntfile.js